# Acces object in an array with php

Tags: php, arrays, object

Hope you can help me.

I've tried so diffrent ways but i'm not able to resolve this problem.

I have an array with objects inside:

```
    Array
(
[1] => CntProviderIncentiveResult Object
    (
        [_StartDate:protected] => 1356303600
        [_EndDate:protected] => 1356908400
        [_ProviderRoom:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 1
        [_RoomName:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => Doble
        [_RoomCode:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 2370
        [_PropertyCode:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => anglers
        [_Occupancy:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_Currency:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_AllocationGroup:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_FreeSaleGroup:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_StopSaleGroup:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_ReleaseGroup:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_MinStayGroup:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] => 
        [_UpdateRequirement:CntProviderIncentiveResult:private] =>
```

)
 )

I try to assign one of the objects to a new array setting the Array Key:

```
$ConfirmRoom = $ConfirmRoomData[$roomKey];
```

Where `$roomKey` is the Key of the array. (1, 20, 21)

and after i verify if is well done:

```
if ($ConfirmRoom instanceof CntProviderIncentiveResult) {echo "OK";}
```

But The new object `$ConfirmRoom` is always empty.

Could you please make me see the light?

Comment: You may want to edit this code and provide only essential data, and since you are having problems on the very first level of this array, we don't need to know all the details of objects inside.

Comment: Tou can't access protected or private indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var_dump($ConfirmRoom)` for starters.

Also, ensure that `isset($ConfirmRoomData[$roomKey])` and that the big array is indeed in `$ConfirmRoomData`.

These are just a few basic debugging steps that may help solve your problem. My guess would be that `$roomKey` is not being properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved:

```
foreach ($ConfirmRoomData as $key => $value) {
if (is_object ($value)) {
if ($key == $roomKey){
                                            $ConfirmRoom = $value;
}
```

}
}